# What does the error mean and how to fix it - "ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to write the code for K-NN

Below is my code. - I know that issue is in `predict() but I am not able to figure out how o fix it.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('UniversalBank.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,[ 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13]].values   #, 
y = dataset.iloc[:,9].values

#Splitting the dataset to training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state= 0)

#Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#Fitting the classifier to training set 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)


#Predicting the test results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Please do not include code that comes after the error, since it is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and just creates unnecessary clutter (removed).

Comment: Help us help you by providing: a short sample of what's in `UniversalBank.csv`.

Comment: Can you please print the shape of the `X_train` and `X_test`?